# React, Typescript, how to use useContext API

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I am new to React and trying to understand the useContext API. I need a generic context provider in which I want to make API call to update the context variable.

Trying to find this kind of solution but could not find it anywhere.

```
import {createContext} from "react";

type AppContextType = {
    SPType: string | undefined
}

type AppContextProps = {
    children: JSX.Element | JSX.Element[];
}

export const AppContext = createContext<AppContextType | undefined>(undefined);

export const AppContextProvider = ({children}: AppContextProps) => {

//I want to make API call here(in this provider) and set SPType from the response

    let providerValue = {
        SPType: 'user'
    }

    return <AppContext.Provider value={providerValue}>{children}</AppContext.Provider>
}

//inside app.tsx
<AppContextProvider>
....
</AppContextProvider>
```

When I am trying to access SPType it is giving this error:

> Property 'SPType' does not exist on type 'AppContextType | undefined'.

Comment: Have looked into this before, I don't think there is away to do it since the consumer can be placed into any provider without knowing the type parameter of the provider. You could do this with a typeguard perhaps if you have a limited number of types that the type parameter can be of. Interested to see if anyone has a solution though

Comment: I'm not sure what nuance I'm missing but this code works fine for me. See this sandbox. https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-ben-81tk2i?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: is it possible to not use this notation ctx?.SPType with question mark because I have a function which need a mandatory prop and if I send this I would get error and main problem here is that I want to make API call which I could not because it throws error invalid hook call when I am using useEffect

Comment: useEffect always runs after a render. The first time through, it won't have a value, unless you give it a default. Alternatively, do not render your component at all if you don't have what you need. This is typical for "loading" patterns. https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/conditional-rendering

Comment: Also, do not conditionally render hooks. Consider using a library like react query and suspense for these concerns. Here is an example, https://codesandbox.io/s/react-query-suspense-cmdq7l?file=/src/index.tsx